# How to hold a plot when using plot3 in matlab?

Tags: matlab, plot, matlab-figure

This works as I expected:

```
    for i=1:100
      hold on;
      plot(i,i^2);
      drawnow;
    end
```

Ploting the points as they come in the same figure.

This on the other hand, doesn't:

```
    for i=1:100
      hold on;
      plot3(i,i^2,sqrt(i));
      drawnow;
    end;
```

Since it does not show a 3d plot of the points, it only shows the projection of them in the xy plane. Somehow the `hold on`statement messes up with plot3.

How can I obtain results that are analogous to the 2d case when using `plot`, in the 3d case, when I have points in several 3d locations?

I've tried to make this question concise, if you believe I haven't explained it well enough for a satisfactory answer please say so in the comments.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your code correctly plots a 3-D curve. All you need to do to see it is add

```
view(3);
```

anywhere in your code.

Additionally, one `hold on` command is sufficient (i.e. you don't need to repeat it in every loop iteration).

Comment: +1. You could also do `hold on` after the first call to `plot3` rather than before - in that case, the default view would be maintained.

Comment: Thank's! Both the answer and the comment were helpful.