# How can I make this code plot lines, instead of points?

Tags: matlab, plot

How can I get the code:

```
    for i = 1:100
      plot3(i,i^2,i^3);
      hold on;
      drawnow;
    end
```

To plot, instead of points, lines conneting the points?

Please take into account that the plotting must be done as the data comes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want lines, you need to give the plotting function at least two points. The following code should plot the current data point indicated by the loop as well as the previous one, linking the two with a line segment.

```
figure; hold on;
for i = 2:100
    lineSeg = [i, i-1];
    plot3(lineSeg, lineSeg.^2, lineSeg.^3);
end
view(3);
```

Edit: I added `view(3)` to be consistent with the answer from the similar existing post here: [How to hold a plot when using plot3 in matlab?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16290687/how-to-hold-a-plot-when-using-plot3-in-matlab)

Answer (score 1):

A slightly more complex option -- if you want to be able to, for example, rotate the plot while it is moving, or change line color in real time, etc, would be to update Xdata, Ydata, and Z data.  (equivalent would be to set xdatasource, etc, and use refreshdata to replot).

```
x=[]; y=[]; z=[]; axis([0 100 0 10^4 0 10^6])
set(gca,'nextPlot','replacechildren')
for i=1:100;
x(end+1)=i; y(end+1)=i^2;z(end+1)=i^3;
if (i==1); h=plot3(x,y,z); else set(h,'Xdata',x,'Ydata',y,'Zdata',z);  pause(0.25); end
end
```

This will let you rotate around, select the line to change color, change marker type, while the plot is unfolding.